# How to use FBJS to get the language preference of the user?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I'm modifying an existing FaceBook application. The FaceBook application is generated by another application, so I don't have much control over it. I can only add html/javascript.

My goal is to use FBJS to detect the current language setting of the user and display a different message depending on their language.

For example, if the user has their language setting set to Spanish, then I would like to show a message in Spanish on my FaceBook application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want with only HTML/JS changes.

I think the fastest way to do this is to use [AJAX in FBJS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/#ajax) to callback to your server.  Server-side, grab `/me` from the Graph API.  [There's a locale field](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) that tells you the user's language setting.  Or do the Graph API server-side call when the page first loads and you can avoid AJAX altogether.  The specifics of how you do this depend on what server-side language you're using.

The "right" way to do this is to let the translation community translate your site for you.  Read [this Internationalization doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/) for more info.  If you're using using FBJS it sounds like this is a FBML app so you'd use some of [these internationalization FBML tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/#platform-internationalization).